# Trouble creating a SQL script in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

So I have some data in column A1 that is typically always numbers but can be different character lengths, I need the output of the sql script to contain it in single quotes ''.

I also have data in column B1 that is always a date which I need it to be contained in single quotes as well as be in the format of mm/dd/yyyy when it's output to the SQL script.

I've been trying to accomplish this with a CONCATENATE formula but I can't seem to get it right.
I've tried formatting column A and B accordingly and it works for those columns but it doesn't transfer the output of the formatting into the script.

Here's an example of the formula I'm using:
`=CONCATENATE("update unit set dtavailable = ",B1," ,dtready = ",B1," where scode = ",A1,""," ","and hproperty = ",C1,"")`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrNdi.png)

Comment: `..." where scode = '",A1,"'",...`

Comment: Thanks! That worked for the scode single quotes!

Comment: Now I need to get the date formatted correctly and in quotes as well.

Comment: `TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyy")`

Comment: `=CONCATENATE("update unit set dtavailable = '",TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyy"),"' ,dtready = '",TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yyy"),"' where scode = '",A1,"'"," ","and hproperty = ",C1,"")`

Comment: Thanks Scott, this will save me a lot of time!